# Как удалить headers content length и transfer encoding в proxyman или charles

Tags: rest, сниффер, charles

Пытаюсь удалить хидеры из запроса и ответа, но они все равно формируются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал через тулзы breakpoint и rewrite, но эти хидеры все равно формируются.

Есть ощущение, что из за них я не могу замокать данные в ответе и запросе

Comment: Для keep-alive соединения присутствие одного из этих заголовков строго обязательно, иначе соединение сломается из-за неопределённости длины тела ответа

Comment: Да, это понял, но ошибка падает именно на них
Error
--------------------------------------------
Error: DioError [DioErrorType.other]: HttpException: Both Content-Length and Transfer-Encoding are specified, at most one is allowed, uri = https://demo.gameram.com/api/v3/public/feed/create